# Can you use builtin_expect with switch statement

Tags: gcc, switch-statement, branch-prediction

I have a `switch` statement in some time-critical code.  I was trying to optimize it with `__builtin_expect`, but it does not seem to be working.  I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if I'm missing some detail, or if the compiler simply does not optimize for it.  I have tried the following on my host machine:

```
int main() {
    volatile int v=0;
    long i = 0;

    for (i=0; i<1000000000L; i++) {
            switch(__builtin_expect(v, EXPT)) {
            case 7:
                    v=7;
                    break;
            default:
                    v=7;
                    break;
            }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Then I compile and run as follows:

```
~/code/builtinexpect> gcc bie.c -o bie -D EXPT=0 && time ./bie 

real    0m2.092s  
user    0m2.086s
sys     0m0.000s
~/code/builtinexpect> gcc bie.c -o bie -D EXPT=7 && time ./bie 

real    0m2.092s
user    0m2.086s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I am using GCC version 4.5.1.

Comment: How does the produced assembly code look like in both cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC does not support this on any architecture I'm aware of.  If you have a `switch` statement which strongly favors a particular case, your best recourse is to do an `if ... else switch ...` statement.  This would result in the optimization you're looking for.

Comment: GCC seems to have added support: <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59521#c20>

Answer (score 3):

Both `case` branches (and therefore *all* cases) do the same thing, so  the compiler is free to replace the whole switch statement with `v=7`. Even if it doesn't (without optimization), would you expect any real difference in timing?

<s>But more to the point, [`__builtin_expect`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) evaluates as `(v == EXPT)`, either `(0)` or `(1)`, so `case 7:` will never be taken.</s>

Comment: He didn't use compiler optimizations, so the code should differ and may cause forced mispredictions, but nice catch about the boolean-ness!

Comment: @Leeor - I like to think a branch-predictor would get it mostly right with a billion iterations:)

Comment: I would hope for a decent __builtin_expect to be strong enough to force the HW not to. Those HW folks need to know their place  :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I shaved down the example to post here to only two case statements (though I had tried it with more, with differing side-effects, but got the same results).  The real-life scenerio is run millions of times per second, and even a 1% improvement would be significant.

Comment: According to [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), "The return value is the value of exp, which should be an integral expression" (it says it _expects_ `exp == c`, but does not say it returns the result of this)...   I just tried it, and case 1 and 0 are never hit if I initialize to -1.